# Problems with time zones on a Micromax unite 3 with Lollipop

Tags: date-and-time, time-zones, micromax-unite

My timezone is GMT +5:30 but it always changes it to GMT +2:00. Please help me fix this problem. This made me miss an important meeting.

Answer (score 2):

I'd first check your settings under `Date & Time` (at the bottom of the settings menu).

**Possibility 1**: Automatic time zone is deselected.

- `Issue`: Your phone is manually setting an incorrect time zone.
- *Solution*: Select `Automatic time zone`

**Possibility 2**: Automatic time zone is selected.

- `Issue`: Your phone is automatically selecting an incorrect timezone
- *Solution*: Set your time zone manually by deselecting `Automatic date & time` and pressing `Select time zone` below and setting it to `Kolkata` or `Colombo` (both GMT +5:30).

Let us know if either of these fixes your issue!